# What is the purpose of the engineering book?

Tags: equipment, wfrp-4e

One of my players on Warhammer Fantasy Role-Play create an Engineer. He get an engineering book (trapping) and ask me if there is any utility for this item (role-play aside).

I didn't find information about that. The rule-book is big so maybe I missed the relevant part. When I asked my friends they weren't able to know if there is any rules about that.

- Maybe it behave like wizard's books?
- If the character didn't spend xp on specific recipe, did he have to use his engineering book?
- Maybe it lower the difficulty for crafting tools or weapons?

Answer (score 3):

There is no game-mechanic that uses the book in RAW in 4e; its fluff.
As a suggestion, it *might* equate to a "Between Adventures" Invent! Endeavour (p.199), or allow a Crafting Endeavour (p.197), but that's my suggestion, not the rules.